# php search date string

Tags: php, mysql, date

ive got few client list with DOB format yyyy-mm-dd.
how do i search client by their Date of birth, even if i enter either year or month or date first, it will show the result.

at the moment, i need to use format yyyy-mm-dd to search them.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT f_name, l_name, dob, email FROM user WHERE dob LIKE'$keyword%' OR f_name LIKE '$keyword%' OR l_name LIKE '$keyword%' LIMIT 100")

if($result) {
  if($db->affected_rows()!= 0){

     // echo the result

  }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here. Can you give us a few examples for what you'll be searching for?

Comment: A side-note: usually, `affected_rows` returns the rows affected by an INSERT, DELETE, REPLACE or UPDATE statement. Not from SELECT, though.

Comment: Are these dates stored as YYYY-MM-DD VARCHAR/CHAR fields, or as DATE fields? Also, am I right in thinking that what you're asking is to input the date as a keyword in any arbitrary format, like "DD/MM/YYYY" or "MM/DD/YYYY"?

Comment: @Wooble its date field. thats correct. any idea how to search the DOB even if the format is different?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `LIKE`, you can use `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `DAY()` to compare against.  Be sure you've properly escaped `$keyword` already...

```
$result = $db->query("
  SELECT f_name, l_name, dob, email
  FROM user 
  WHERE
    // The year, month, or day can be an exact match (note parentheses)
    (YEAR(dob) = '$keyword' OR MONTH(dob) = '$keyword' OR DAY(dob) = '$keyword')
    // Or the full yyyy-mm-dd date can be an exact match
    OR DATE(dob) = '$keyword'
    // OR UK date format
    OR DATE(dob) = STR_TO_DATE('$keyword', '%d/%m/%y')
    // or the rest of your conditions...
    OR f_name LIKE '$keyword%' OR l_name LIKE '$keyword%' LIMIT 100"
);
```

**EDIT**: added quotes around integer date components, to avoid syntax errors for when strings rather than numbers are searched.

Comment: thanks youre really helpful :). i forgot somthing to ask in the question. is it possible to search DOB with UK format (dd/mm/yyyy) even though the date format in database is (yyyy-mm-dd)? how do i do that :)

Comment: @boyee007 Maybe via `STR_TO_DATE()`.  See addition above. I'm not sure if the function call will fail if the input doesn't match the format dd/mm/yy.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it would be better to normalize date in PHP:

```
$date = strtotime($keyword);
$result = $db->query('
  SELECT f_name, l_name, dob, email
  FROM user 
  WHERE
    f_name LIKE "$keyword%"
    OR l_name LIKE "$keyword%"
    '.($date&&$date!=-1?'OR dob="'.date('Y-m-d',$date).'"':'').'
  LIMIT 100
');
```